# The “injection” tag on stack overflow is not very useful

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

I seem that the [injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/injection) tag (likewise [dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dependency)) is normally used when [dependency-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dependency-injection) or [sql-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-injection) tags should be used.

Should it be black listed for new questions to as to guide people to more useful tags?

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are several more tags containing "injection", including [`code-injection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-injection), [`constructor-injection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/constructor-injection), [`dll-injection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dll-injection) and [`policy-injection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/policy-injection), to mention just those which are used more than 10 times.

So all posts currently tagged `injection` should be carefully retagged manually to some of these existing tags <strike>before blacklisting</strike> eventually.

Comment: that way I said "black listed for NEW" quesions.  The retagging will take a long time, meanwhile the "injection" tat will keep being used for new questions.

Comment: @Ian, I missed the "new", sorry. It would make sense, although I have no idea if it is technically possible on SO currently.